# How to transpose tabular organizational hierarchy data in python?

Tags: python

**I have a csv dataset that is similar in structure to the following table in tabular form:**

| Employee | Manager |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | E |
| C | E |
| D | B |
| E | H |
| F | H |
| G | H |
| H |  |

**How would I go about in python transforming this so that I can list out the Employee's reports if they have any. So with the above table I would want to transform it to look something like this:**

| Employee | Manager | Report 1 | Report 2 | Report 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B |  |  |  |
| B | E | A | D |  |
| C | E |  |  |  |
| D | B |  |  |  |
| E | H | B | C |  |
| F | H |  |  |  |
| G | H |  |  |  |
| H |  | E | F | G |

Comment: It looks like you just want to add additional columns to your df? Please edit the post to include what you have attempted so far and include a minimal reproducible example. Pandas `pd.read_csv` and `df.insert` will likely be able to accomplish what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough to get all the reports for an employee as a list using a groupby operation. More difficult to explode it into new columns. Currently runs fine, but with a `FutureWarning` complaining about incompatible types. Hopefully someone has a cleaner solution to this.

```
# Gather reports
reports = df.groupby('Manager')['Employee'].unique()
reports = reports.reset_index().rename(columns = {'Manager': 'Employee', 'Employee': 'Reports'})

# Generate new report columns based on largest number of reports for an employee
max_reports = reports['Reports'].str.len().max()

report_cols = [f'Report{i+1}' for i in range(max_reports)]

# Merge with original DF
df2 = df.merge(reports, how = 'left', on = 'Employee')

# Explode out reports into separate columns
df2.loc[~df2['Reports'].isna(), report_cols] = pd.DataFrame(df2.loc[~df2['Reports'].isna(), 'Reports'].to_list()).values
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to first `pivot` and `tranform` the data frame:

```
# Pivot and then transform to move all Nans to the end and then drop it
df2 = df.pivot(index = 'Manager', columns='Employee', values='Employee')
df2 = df2.transform(lambda x: sorted(x, key=pd.isnull), axis=1) 
df2 = df2.dropna(axis=1,how='all')

# rename and merge
df2.columns = [f'Reports_{i+1}'  for i in range(len(df2.columns))]
df.merge(df2, left_on = ['Employee'], right_index=True, how='left')
```

Output:

```
  Employee Manager Reports_1 Reports_2 Reports_3
0        A       B       NaN       NaN       NaN
1        B       E         A         D       NaN
2        C       E       NaN       NaN       NaN
3        D       B       NaN       NaN       NaN
4        E       H         B         C       NaN
5        F       H       NaN       NaN       NaN
6        G       H       NaN       NaN       NaN
7        H     NaN         E         F         G
```